# Any better way to declare variables avoiding repetition of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is the js code which i am trying to use. I don't like the same code repeating again and I couldn't help myself to do this in a better way.

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-behavior~=quick-reject]').on("click", function(){
    var form = $(this).closest("[data-behavior~=modal-footer]").find("form");
    var some_action = form.find("#some_actions").val();
    var some_reasons = form.find("[data-behavior~=escalation-reason-select-box]");

    if((some_reasons.val() === "") && ( some_action === "reject")){
      var errorReason = "Please select a reason";
      form.addClass("error").
      parent().
      find("div.error").
      html(errorReason);
    }else{
      form.submit();
    }
  });

  $(document).on("change", "#some_actions", function (){
    var form = $(this).closest("[data-behavior~=modal-footer]").find("form");
    var some_action = form.find("#some_actions").val();
    var some_reasons = form.find("[data-behavior~=escalation-reason-select-box]");

    if(some_action === "verify"){
      some_reasons.hide();
    }else{
      some_reasons.show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The code isn't the same - it does something different if you click vs change some_actions.  The change event could use "this" instead of form/form.find if you really don't like using the same code, but the actual *actions* are not repeated, only obtaining the elements to action upon.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a little utility function, something like.

```
function getVars(that) {
  var form = $(that).closest("[data-behavior~=modal-footer]").find("form");
  return {
    form: form,
    some_action: form.find("#some_actions").val(),
    some_reasons: form.find("[data-behavior~=escalation-reason-select-box]")
  }
}

$('[data-behavior~=quick-reject]').on("click", function(){
    var v = getVars(this);
    if((v.some_reasons.val() === "") && ( v.some_action === "reject")){
      var errorReason = "Please select a reason";
      v.form.addClass("error").
      parent().
      find("div.error").
      html(errorReason);
    }else{
      v.form.submit();
    }
});

$(document).on("change", "#some_actions", function (){
    var v = getVars(this);
    if(v.some_action === "verify"){
      v.some_reasons.hide();
    }else{
      v.some_reasons.show();
    }
});
```